# How to Properly read an excel with date format problems in R

Tags: excel, date-format, openxlsx

I Have an excel file with blood sample results (i.e. Insuline and Glycemia).

The problem is that there are some cells on that excel file that have a wrong format, they have the insulin results as a personalized date format (d.m), therefore the result looks like 18.3 (which is reasonable) but when I try to read the file in R, it looks like a numeric date = 44273 (March 18th, 2021).

I've been trying to fix it at the excel file, but I haven't been able to do it. Does anybody has an idea of how to fix this problem?

Best Regards!

Comment: Fix it in Excel, so the correct value is stored in the cell.  If it is the case that the dot is your date-part separator, you may need to enter the value as `=18.3` instead of just typing it in.

Answer (score 0):

you could use package readxl and use the col_types argument to read in the column as numeric. Below would be reading 4th column as numeric:

```
library(readxl)

read_excel("blood_sample.xlsx", col_types = c("logical", "skip", "guess", "numeric"))
```

Read more here: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html